# How to add more than one element to a custom Menu in TinyMCE 4 and display its content on the editor canvas when clicked?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to add a menu with different options in TinyMCE4 and when I click one element the text of the option in the editor canvas. I successfully added the menu with one option only with the following code I found:

```
tinymce.init({
          language: 'es',
          selector: '#plantillaEditor',
          height : '500',
          width : '300',
          menu : {
                file   : {title : 'File'  , items : 'newdocument'},
                edit   : {title : 'Edit'  , items : 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
                insert : {title : 'Insert', items : 'link media | template hr'},
                view   : {title : 'View'  , items : 'visualaid'},
                format : {title : 'Format', items : 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
                table  : {title : 'Table' , items : 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
                tools  : {title : 'Tools' , items : 'code'},
                tags: {title : 'Etiquetas', items : 'newmenuitem'}
            },
          menubar: 'file edit format table tags',
          setup: function(editor) {
                editor.addMenuItem('newmenuitem', {
                    text: 'new menu',
                    context: 'tags',
                    onclick: function () { console.log(this); }
                }
                );
            },
          readonly: ((getUrlVars()["mode"]=='view') ? true : false),
          plugins:'image imagetools link fullscreen fullpage textcolor colorpicker advlist autolink autosave charmap code contextmenu insertdatetime save print table',
          toolbar: "customToolbar undo redo | save | print | styleselect | forecolor backcolor | bold italic | "+
               "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | table bullist numlist outdent indent | "+
               " link | image  | charmap code | insertdatetime",
          insertdatetime_formats: ["%H:%M", "%d-%m-%Y", "%S:%M:%I %p", "Buenos Aires, %d de %B de %Y"],
          contextmenu: "copy | cut | paste | link image imageupload | cell row column deletetable",
          autosave_interval: "60s",
          paste_data_images: true,

          save_onsavecallback: function () {

                var bodyHtml=$editor.val().match(/(?:.(?!<\s*body[^>]*>))*\>.+/)[0];
                var mode='<?php echo $mode?>';
                var namePattern;
                var namePrefix;
                var textAreaName;


                      if(mode!=='user'){  
                         var request = $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/editor/processDataHtml',
                            data: {  editorData: bodyHtml, 
                                     id_acto_doc_plantilla : '<?php echo $id_acto_doc_plantilla; ?>'         
                                        },
                            success: function(data) {
                               alert(data);
                                },
                            error: function(data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                             })
                       }else{

                                $htmlInputParent.val(bodyHtml);

                          }
                }
         });
```

I have to solve 2 things:

1)How can I add more than one element to the menu?. There's no documentation on the "setup:" parameter showing and example and I tried adding another "date" element on to the menu:

```
                tags: {title : 'Etiquetas', items : 'newmenuitem date'}
```

and then the setup parameter with more than one element:

```
                  setup: function(editor) {
            editor.addMenuItem('newmenuitem', {
                text: 'new menu',
                context: 'tags',
                onclick: function () { console.log(this); }
            }),
            editor.addMenuItem('date', {
                text: 'Date',
                context: 'tags',
                onclick: function () { console.log(this); }
            });
        },
```

But it doesn't seem to work.....

2)The second problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the text value of the option on the menu when the element is clicked. When I log "this" I've searched among the properties of the object and I couldn't find a prop that holds the value of the item.

Does someone know how can I do these 2 things?

EDIT: I solved the issue # 1) ....it was just a typo, the correct code for the setup: parameter is:

```
            tags: {title : 'Etiquetas', items : 'newmenuitem date'},

>  setup: function(editor) {
>               editor.addMenuItem('newmenuitem', {
>                   text: 'new menu',
>                   context: 'tags',
>                   onclick: function () { console.log(this); }
>               });
>               editor.addMenuItem('date', {
>                   text: 'Date',
>                   context: 'tags',
>                   onclick: function () { console.log(this); }
>               });
>           },
```

The issue #2) is still not working. I tried to log to the console the text content of the menu option using javascript and jquery as well without luck, the object is returned properly but when I filter the properties of the object using javascript console I can't find the attribute.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the settings attribute of the object that `this` returns will have what you need:

```
editor.addMenuItem('menuitem1', {
    text: 'Text for Menu Item 1',
    context: 'tags',
    onclick: function () { 
        console.log(this.settings.text); 
    }
});
```

Note that you can even add custom attributes to the object you pass to the `addMenuItem` method and access those at runtime:

```
editor.addMenuItem('menuitem1', {
    text: 'Text for Menu Item 1',
    customAttrib: 'Colorado Avalanche',
    context: 'tags',
    onclick: function () { 
        console.log(this.settings.text);
        console.log(this.settings.customAttrib); 
    }
});
```

The second `console.log` is referencing the `customAttrib` attribute which is not part of the required attributes.  TinyMCE is just expecting a valid JavaScript object so you can put whatever you like in there as long as you put the things TinyMCE requires.

Comment: great answer my friend. I can see the value now in an alert. However, I tried to append it to the textarea div that holds the content of the editor and it doesn't get appended

         $("#plantillaEditor").append(this.settings.text);   

It doesn't throw any error. I also tried

         $("#plantillaEditor").html(this.settings.text);

and

         $("#plantillaEditor").text(this.settings.text);   

and 

            $("#plantillaEditor").val(this.settings.text);   

without any success.....Don't you know how to do that?

Comment: I already solved it, to insert something on the current position once the menu item is clicked you can use:

      tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, " text you want to insert");